# Doubts about IIP3 (Third Order Intercept Point)

Tags: power, amplifier, rf, power-electronics, frequency

I was reading the chapter of the book "The Design of CMOS Radio-frequency Integrated Circuits " (Thomas H. Lee) about linearity of power amplifiers. It introduces the definition of IIP3 by saying that in general the output current of a transistor amplifier is a non-linear function of the input signal, which may be approximated as a 3rd degree polynomial (if the input signal is quite small):

[image]

Now it analyzes the situation in which the input signal \$v\$ is the sum of two sine with frequencies \$\omega1\$ and \$\omega2\$.

[image]

If we put this expression inside that of the current we get the complete formula. But the most important terms are the first order term (which is the linear term) and the intermodulation products, which are respectively:

- DC term and Linear term (note that also the \$v^3\$ term generates a linear component):
  [image]
- Intermodulation products:
  [image]

Then, it introduces IIP3:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Now, I have the following questions:

1) The book finds IIP3 by putting the amplitude coefficient of the intermodulation product equal to c1A. But it is not the complete amplitude of the linear term: there is also a linear term which comes from \$v^3\$, as we have already said. Why is the last term ignored? I think that a correct definition of IIP3 should compare the total amplitude of the linear signal (so not only c1A) with the total amplitude of the intermodulation product.

2) After having found the expression of A, it finds IIP3 by evaluating the input power corresponding to A. My question is about how to evaluate it: the input signal is the sum of two sine waves, and so, when we use the formula

IIP3 = \$A^2 /(2Rs)\$

what does the factor 2 represent? Is it due to the fact that we should use rms values of amplitude, or to the fact that the the input resistance of the amplifier is supposed to be equal to Rs (source resistance)?

Comment: Dividing by 2R gives the intersection of power for C1,C3

Answer (score 1):

IIP3 assumes that the nonlinearity is small -- so the polynomial coefficients C2 and C3 are small. As you noted at the beginning of the question, the input amplitude is also small. Therefore A^3 << A. Therefore (in the limit) there is no difference between using C1 or (C1+9/4.C3.A^2).

Answer (score 0):

The doubt with IP3 is related to the fact that a detailed study of the 3:1 slope shows a change in slope to 4:1 and then back to 3:1.  This is related to the fact the linear S parameters cannot predict the effect.  The non-linear S Parameters will show the change related to the fact that there is also a second order effect with an intercept point slope that is passing thru the third order slope.  Third order is an effect created by the multiplication of the two second harmonic signals while the second order is related to the voltage distortion near the peak of each signal.  To understand this consider summing two signals phase locked to a common reference separated by 5 MHz into a perfectly linear scope.  You will see a sine wave with a peak amplitude variation of 5 MHz.  This modulation is time varying the third and second order effect and testing equipment for third IM does not give the true result because of BW issues which average.  Analysis with non-linear Sparameters allows each product to be shown and at the same time the combined effect which makes the third IM slope vary.  Saw this in testing and then analyzed with RF CAD SW.